# Torchlight 2, what is the keyboard shortcut equivelant for the zooming mouse wheel?

Tags: torchlight-2, keyboard

In Torchlight 2 what are the keyboard shortcut keys for players who don't have a scrolling mouse wheel (or in my case one who uses a pen and tablet instead of a mouse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR: - to zoom out = to zoom in, but these can be edited with the below steps

A quick check of the steam forums says the - key will zoom out and the = will zoom in.

There should be a "Controls" menu under Options that will let you re-assign functions to other keys. There should be an option to change zoom from mouse wheel to whatever you would like.

If that doesn't work for you, someone on the Steam Community wrote an entire guide for editing your settings.txt file to create the customization you want:

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=132746185

In particular you would be looking for the definitions of the variables and the definitions of the hotkeys. There it will tell you what you will want to change and what number the key you're interested in is.

For example, if you wanted to use this method to re-assign zoom in to Page Up, you would change settings.txt so that KEYMAP_ZOOMIN :187 read as KEYMAP_ZOOMIN :33.

Good luck!

Comment: On the Mac version of the game, it was not set up to the '-' key and the '=' key. But thanks for pointing out the controls button so I set it up myself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were they keys? Or did it just say mouse wheel?

Comment: It just said mouse wheel up 'mwu' and the other key was mouse wheel down 'mwd', if I remember the mneumonics correctly.